XSD - extend base restriction type
I've the following type definitions:
<xsd:simpleType name="T_YES_NO">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:enumeration value="y" />
    <xsd:enumeration value="n" />
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:simpleType name="T_FORBIDDEN">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:enumeration value="f" />
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

I would like to restrict a type T_FOOBAR as
<xsd:simpleType name="T_FOOBAR">
  <xsd:restriction base="T_YES_NO" />
  <xsd:restriction base="T_FORBIDDEN" /> <!-- Not allowed -->
</xsd:simpleType>

and I don't want to write
<xsd:simpleType name="T_FOOBAR">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:enumeration value="y" />
    <xsd:enumeration value="n" />
    <xsd:enumeration value="f" />
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

How to do that?

Showing code that doesn't work isn't a good way of explaining your requirements. If your requirement is to allow "y", "n", or "f" as valid values, then say so!

It sounds as if you could solve this particular use case with a union type: https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#UnionDt.
<xsd:simpleType name="T_FOOBAR">
  <xsd:union memberTypes="T_YES_NO T_FORBIDDEN"/>
</xsd:simpleType>

